# Bash script help - convert bunch of .lit files to .txt files, remove spaces in file names

Tags: bash, scripting

So I have the following files

```
Eoin Colfer - Artemis Fowl 01 - Artemis Fowl.lit
Eoin Colfer - Artemis Fowl 02 - The Arctic Incident.lit
```

And so forth. I want to take each of these lit files in different directories, use Calibre's ebook-convert to change them into .txt files, strip the file names of spaces. So far, here's what I have got.

find eBOOKS -type f -iname '*.lit' -exec ebook-convert '{}' '{}'.txt

Now, how do I remove the spaces in the file names, and how do I remove the .lit in the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has the Perl script called `rename`:

```
rename 's/ //g;s/.lit.txt$/.txt/' *.lit.txt
```